# Simplify $\frac{1}{h}\Big( \frac{1}{(x-a-h)^2} - \frac{1}{(x-a)^2}\Big)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

> Simplify $\frac{1}{h}\Big( \frac{1}{(x-a-h)^2} - \frac{1}{(x-a)^2}\Big)$

I would like a little help, so that I can finish solving this exercise.
So far, I've got
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{(x-a-h)^2} - \frac{1}{(x-a)^2}}{h}
= \frac{\frac{(x-a)^2 - (x-a-h)^2}{(x-a-h)^2(x-a)^2}}{h}
= \frac{\frac{(x-a)^2 - (x-a-h)^2}{(x-a-h)^2(x-a)^2}}{ \frac{h}{1}}
= \frac{(x-a)^2 - (x-a-h)^2}{h(x-a-h)^2(x-a)^2}
$$
In the numerator maybe I can continue with a difference of squares, but I'm a little confused.

Comment: And what does difference of squares give you?

Comment: $\ ((x-a)+(x-a-h)) ((x-a)-(x-h-a)) $

Comment: @Brian Exactly...and now you can simplify a little more, if you want to.

Comment: "Simplify" is an ambiguous request. You would usually "simplify" an expression for a purpose, say to find roots or to integrate a function, etc. All the given solutions represent Algebraic manipulations that don't necessarily provide a simpler term.

Answer (score 3):

The top simplifies 
$$ (x-a)^2 -[(x-a)-h]^2 =$$

$$(x-a)^2 -[(x-a)^2-2h(x-a)+h^2]$$

$$=2h(x-a)-h^2$$

Comment: $\ \frac{h(2(x-a)-h)}{h(x-a-h)^2(x-a)^2} $ here I can cancel h

Comment: Very good, keep up the good work.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Begin by putting
$$x-a=b$$
then

$$\frac{1}{(b-h)^2}-\frac{1}{b^2}=$$
$$\frac{b^2-(b-h)^2}{b^2(b-h)^2}=$$

$$\frac{h(2b-h)}{b^2(b-h)^2}.$$

And if we divide by h, one find

$$\frac{2(x-a)-h}{(x-a)^2(x-a-h)^2}.$$

Comment: if you use $y=b-h$, the expression would "look" much simpler in terms of $b$ and $y$.

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{(x-a)^2 - (x-a-h)^2}{h(x-a-h)^2(x-a)^2}=\frac{\left((x-a)-(x-a-h)\right)\left((x-a)+(x-a-h)\right)}{h(x-a-h)^2(x-a)^2}=$$

$$=\frac{h(2x-2a-h)}{h(x-a-h)^2(x-a)^2}=\frac{(2x-2a-h)}{(x-a-h)^2(x-a)^2}$$

If now you want to take the limit when $\;h\to0\;$ , for example, the above equals

$$\frac2{(x-a)^3}$$

Comment: I agree, but for my case I should only use algebraic expressions, for now I should not use calculus.